# How to measure text extent using DWrite?

Tags: c#, directwrite

How can I get the text extent with DirectWrite?
.Net provides it as part of the [FormattedText class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.extent.aspx), for example.

Answer (score 14):

Create an `IDWriteTextLayout` set up the way you want, and then use methods such as `DetermineMinWidth()` and `GetMetrics()` to retrieve the layout calculations.